# Python Pandas: What is the fastest way to calculate days between two date?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to calculate elapsed days like this:

```
df["elapsed_days"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.logged_day - x.registered_day).days, axis=1)
```

The type of logged_day and registered_day is datetime.date().
It takes long time to calculate days (maybe) - 40 seconds per 30,0000 records. 
Is there anything else I can do to speed things up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas) has you covered:

```
In [252]: s - s.max()
Out[252]: 
0   -2 days
1   -1 days
2    0 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [253]: s - datetime(2011,1,1,3,5)
Out[253]: 
0   364 days, 20:55:00
1   365 days, 20:55:00
2   366 days, 20:55:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [254]: s + timedelta(minutes=5)
Out[254]: 
0   2012-01-01 00:05:00
1   2012-01-02 00:05:00
2   2012-01-03 00:05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [255]: s + Minute(5)
Out[255]: 
0   2012-01-01 00:05:00
1   2012-01-02 00:05:00
2   2012-01-03 00:05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [256]: s + Minute(5) + Milli(5)
Out[256]: 
0   2012-01-01 00:05:00.005000
1   2012-01-02 00:05:00.005000
2   2012-01-03 00:05:00.005000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I think the second example is the same situation. The calculation(datetime - datetime) takes long time to finish.

I need to calculate another methods (may be date - date)

Comment: I suspect that using a timedelta might be a wee bit faster than subtracting datetimes?